# AWS CDK CfnDistribution attrDomainName '<unresolved-token>'

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, aws-cdk

Having an issue where I can’t get CfnDistribution.attrDomainName to resolve. The value is always '’. I’m trying to inject the value into a Lambda to achieve something like https://github.com/aws-samples/cloudfront-authorization-at-edge/blob/master/template.yaml . Anyone have any guidance? I’ve tried manually setting dependencies and adding a while loop w/ Token.isUnresolved just hangs indefinitely. Thanks in advance for any insight

```
const cloudfrontDistro = new cloudfront.CfnDistribution(this,'CloudFront', {...})

...

new cfn.CustomResource(this, 'CustomCR', {
      provider: cfn.CustomResourceProvider.fromLambda(myProvider),
      properties: {
        CognitoAuthDomain: userPoolDomain.getAttString('DomainName')
      }
    });
```

Comment: just to make sure, you try to get the attrDomainName from cloudfrontDistro ?

Answer (score 0):

was able to fix this issue by getting reference to the variable outside of the `properties` field of the CustomResource. Not sure if the call to Lazy was necessary.

```
const cognitoAuthDomain = cdk.Lazy.stringValue({
      produce: () => {
        return userPoolDomain.getAttString('DomainName')
      }
    });
```